# slab classes and memory allocation in memcached

Tags: caching, memory, memcached, libmemcache, slab

I recently started going through memcached source code and i came across this structure. Based on my understanding, there are approximately 64 slabs and and each slab represents a unique chunk size. If we took the first slab class ( size 80 , say ) then the pages which are belongs to this slab will have it's memory broken into 80 bytes.

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned int size;      // sizes of items
  unsigned int perslab;   // how many items per slab

  void *slots;            // list of item ptrs
  unsigned int sl_curr;   // total free items in list

  unsigned int slabs;     // how many slabs were allocated for this class

  void **slab_list;       // array of slab pointers
  unsigned int list_size; // size of prev array

  size_t requested;       // The number of requested bytes

} slabclass_t;
```

I do not understand this line,

```
unsigned int slabs;     // how many slabs were allocated for this class
```

What does he mean by how many slabs were allocated for a slab class? Every slab class must be unique right? why will there be multiple slabs within one slab class? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

An allocated slab of class `slabclass_t` is basically a chunk of memory that hosts `perslab` number of items of size `size`. If all the items in that slab are used, Memcached allocates another chunk of memory and adds it to the `slab_list`. These chunks of memory are also referred to as `pages` or `slab_pages`.

So if you start a new Memcached server and store one item for a slab class (say size=80), then for this slab class `slabs=1`. Once you store `perslab+1` items in that class you will have `slabs=2` and the `slab_list` will contain 2 items.

Basically, you have a `slab_list` and `slabs` its length whereas `list_size` is its capacity.

I derived most of this from [slabs.c](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/3b11d16b3f92c51bfedbb092147e1c2b225945ff/slabs.c) so correct me if I got something wrong.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the explanation. I'm still confused over what's the difference between pages and slabs? You mentioned that an allocated slab is basically a chunk of memory that hosts `perslab` number of items of size `size`. Does the "item" here refer to a chunk since I understood chunk as basic building blocks that store items in the cache? And when you refer to slab, is the same as slab_page or page?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. When I wrote "chunk of memory" I just meant a piece/region/slice of memory. You are right, `chunks` are the blocks that store the items. So a `slab` has `perslab` chunks that each holds one item.

Comment: Yes, as I mention above, `slabs` are also called `pages` or `slab_pages`.